# How do you change the starting view of a panoramic photo in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, photos

I just uploaded a few panoramic (360) photos to Facebook.  I would like to change the starting view of each one.  I have done this in the past, but I am no longer able to do so.

When I am viewing one of the photos, and I click on Options at the bottom, I see the following:

[image]

When I click on the Edit button, I see the following:

[image]

None of these allows me to change the starting view.  I tried both Firefox and Chrome.  I also tried the Facebook iOS app (per [this link](https://www.facebook.com/help/1034992109915258?helpref=related)) and couldn't do it in there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to set the starting view of a 360 photo is *during* the upload process.  You cannot change it after the photo has been uploaded.

After you have selected a panoramic photo for a post, the Create Post dialog box will have a paintbrush icon on the thumbnail of the photo:

[image]

Click on the paintbrush icon, drag your mouse to select the starting view, and then click Save:

[image]

Then click Post to finish uploading the photo to Facebook.  Once you click Post, you cannot change the starting view anymore.